# How to prevent Google & Ask Alexa to open from MyApp

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager, google-now

I'm recording the audio via Bluetooth earbuds. As and when user press & hold button, App records the audio/voice from Bluetooth earbuds, which is working fine.

**Issue** : While user press & hold button, sometimes `Open with` popup appears asking to open the `Google or Ask Alexa` Apps. (Attaching the screenshots for better understanding)

- How can we prevent this `open with` popup to appear on our App?
- Do I need to add/update any `intent-filter` in `manifest` file?
- Do I need to change mode in `audiomanager` ?

Using following code for Bluetooth audio:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using action voice command?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf nop, I'm not using ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:exported="false"` in your manifest in the activity

```
<activity android:name=com.mymundane.app.MainActivity" 
    android:exported="false">
</activity>
```